remove .html from URL for slice .htaccess - Distinguishing Between Directories and Files
I wrote an .htaccess file to remove .html from the end of file links, but it ended up opening the products directory instead of the products.html file. I want to find a way for it not to open the directory and instead open the file.
Right now, when I click on the link example.com/products/, it opens the directory, but I want it to open the products.html file instead. Also, when I click on the link example.com/products/example2, the page opens without any problem. What's the solution?
Directory structure:

index.html
products.html
products/

example.html
example2.html



.htaccess file:
DirectoryIndex index.html

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/([^.]+)\.html[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>


"when I click on the link example.com/products/" - Does your link actually include the trailing slash? Do you specifically want to have a trailing slash on this URL? However, it looks like the URL should be /products only (without a trailing slash), since your other pages (that map to .html files) also do not have a trailing slash. You should be consistent with the trailing slash across your URLs. (However, I realise that /product will be 301 redirecting to /product/ at the moment because this exists as a physical directory.)

Easiest solution: Rename products.html into products/index.html
Source: From CBroe's comment.
